# Taylor Expanding around a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

I was looking at some notes and found the following Taylor expansion
$$
g(x-f(x)) = g(x) - f(x)g'(x) + \frac{f(x)^2}{2}g''(x) -\ldots
$$
in which the function $g(x)$ is expanded around the function $f(x)$. However I have never seen this done before (only done with constants) and was wondering if this is acceptable or if something else needs to be taken into consideration?

Making the question more direct: Is it acceptable to treat the function as something you can expand around as if it was a constant? If not can you give an counter example? The end goal is to create a series to "remove" the $f(x)$ from inside of $g(x)$ if there is another way to do that

Comment: This is just the composition of Taylor series

Comment: When you fix $x\in \mathbb R$, then $-f(x)\in \mathbb R$ is a real number, so the taylor series of $g$ at $a=x\in \mathbb R$ for displacement $h=-f(x)\in \mathbb R$, can be done, say $g(a+h)=g(a)+g'(a)h+\cdots$